# How to use python generic hints to indicate value type in parent class?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-3.10

I have a static member that will be some implementation of `ToolInterface` interface. I inherit the class that has that member and want to specify what implementation is used.

I tried this:

##### `tool_test_base.py`

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from abstract_tool import ToolInterface


TToolImpl = TypeVar("TToolImpl", ToolInterface)

class ToolTestBase(Generic[TToolImpl]):

    tool_impl = None # type: TToolImpl

    @test_case
    test_do_something(self):
        assert self.tool_impl.do_something() == "hello"
```

##### `abstract_tool.py`

```
def ToolInterface:
    def do_something():
        assert False, "Tool method not implemented"
```

Now I have a class that extends the tool test and also provides a specific implementation:

##### `my_tool.py`

```
from abstract_tool import ToolInterface
class MyTool(ToolInterface):
    do_something(self):
        return "hello"
    do_something_special(self):
        return ""
```

##### `my_tool_test.py`

```
from tool_test_base import ToolTestBase
from my_tool import MyTool

class MyToolTest(ToolTestBase[MyTool]):
    test_something_special(self):
    assert self.tool_impl.do_something_special() == ""
```

Now by writing `ToolTestBase[MyTool]` I was hoping to indicate that `TToolImpl` is `MyTool` and not `MyToolBase`. However, it is not working as intended. I see `tool_impl` hints for `MyToolBase` but not for `MyTool`

Comment: Specializing the generic type is something you do for an *instance*, not a subclass. Tying a *class* attribute to the generic type is awkward at best, impossible at worst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it almost correct. The only mistake is that writing this:

```
TToolImpl = TypeVar("TToolImpl", ToolInterface)
```

means `TToolImpl` can **only** be `ToolInterface`. The correct formulation is:

```
TToolImpl = TypeVar("TToolImpl", bound=ToolInterface)
```

This says that `TToolImpl` is any sub type of `ToolInterface`. After that, it worked for me.